# How to use filter for more than one parameter of a JSON message

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm using ESB-4.9.0 version.

An ESB mediation flow has to be continued based on two filtering logic. JSON message is transformed in the mediation flow. Currently, I'm using two Filter mediators to achieve this. **Is there any possibility to use a single filter mediator to fulfill the same scenario?**

**Input JSON message**

```
{
  "filterId": "CorrectId",
  "approvalStatus": "approved",
  "lifeCycleStatus": "BRANCH_READY",
  "channelData": [
    {
      "status": "pending",
      "indexId": "correctIndexId",
      "description": "Test Description"
    }
  ]
}
```

**The used ESB Synapse part**

```
<filter description="" regex="CorrectId" source="json-eval($.filterId)">
        <then>
           <filter description="" regex="correctIndexId" source="json-eval($.indexId)">
                <then>
                   <!-- continue the mediation flow-1-->
                </then>
                <else>
                    <!-- continue the mediation flow-2-->
                </else>
            </filter>
        </then>
        <else>
            <drop/>
        </else>
    </filter>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible with a filter mediator and the xpath `concat` function:

```
<resource methods="POST" uri-template="/onefilter">
  <inSequence>
     <property name="filterId" expression="json-eval($.filterId)"/>
     <property name="correctIndexId" expression="json-eval($.channelData[0].indexId)"/>
     <property name="combinedID" expression="fn:concat($ctx:filterId, $ctx:correctIndexId)"/>
     <filter source="$ctx:combinedID" regex="CorrectIdcorrectIndexId">
        <then>
           <log level="custom">
              <property name="message" value="continue 1"/>
           </log>
           <drop/>
        </then>
        <else>
           <log level="custom">
              <property name="message" value="continue 2"/>
           </log>
           <drop/>
        </else>
     </filter>
  </inSequence>
```

By the way your code snippet would NEVER go into the `continue 1` route because your JSON path is invalid.